# Checking if email id already exists in database using JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I want that a particular email id shouldn't be used more than once when doing registration. Here's my code:

```
if(request.getParameter("btn1")!=null)
  {
      String unm=request.getParameter("nm");
      String em=request.getParameter("email");
      String pwd=request.getParameter("pass");
      Connect c1=new Connect();
       String q="insert into register(name,email,password) values('"+unm+"','"+em+"','"+pwd+"');";
    int rs=c1.DMLExecuter(q);
    if(rs>0)
    %>
    <script>
        alert("You are registered now. Please login to continue.");
    </script>
```

What should I do to check if the email id is being used twice?

Comment: Short: Make email column in DB as primary key. Long: execute select query first with parameter email check for existence and then insert.

Comment: please!!! use PreparedStatement's...

Comment: please!!!#2 don't store raw passwords in a database. Little bobby tables will otherwise steal all of them.

Answer (score 1):

1. ensure that your email field is unique, such as by adapting the DDL accordingly (this will get the database to ensure that e-mail addresses are unique). Alternatively, the e-mail field could be made primary key:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE register(
       ...
       EMAIL VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
       ...
   )
   ```
2. In the code, before inserting, check the count of existing e-mails by that ID:

   ```
   long existingCount = ...
   String countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM register WHERE email = ?"
   ```

Run this query with the value of `request.getParameter("email")`.
The result should be a number telling you the number of **existing** users with that e-mail.

Assuming that count has been stored in the `existingCount` variable:

```
if(existingCount == 0) {
    //Put here the code to insert the new user as shown in your question...
} else {
%>
    <script>
        alert("You are already registered. Login or choose a different email");
    </script>
<%
}
```

**Note that my sql used bind variables**, please use a prepared statement

Comment: Thank you for the solution :)